# Foundation interchange is not working with extension less image

Tags: javascript, foundation

I am trying to use the foundation interchange script to set the background image for a `div` for different viewport sizes. It works fine with the image with an extension like below

https://test.com/is/image//content/dam/test/images/training/training-banner-mobile.png?$Large2Column50pct$, small

But it throws garbage on the screen for the below setup, you can see the image with no extension

https://s7d1.scene7.com/is/image/test/developer-conf, small

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMGYB.png)

Any idea how to fix it?

> Foundation version: `6.7.3`